# How to multi-select and deselect rows in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, multi-select, deselect

In short, the exact effect I'm trying to achieve is that of the following scenario:

You have a DataGridView with a couple of rows and the DataGridView.MultiSelect property set to true.

If you hold CTRL and click on rows, you can not only select rows, but even deselect the ones already selected - but you cannot do it without holding control.

How do I achieve a similar affect?

When I click on multiple DataGridView rows (individually), the DataGridView selections behaves as if the CTRL button is clicked.

If that is not possible (I've seen it on another project :() then how can it be made that DataGridViewRows are selected on one click, and deselected if not already selected?

Comment: So you want to  force the user to de-select row by row, right? - What about shilft-Selecting? Do you want it or not?

Comment: I can compromise on that.

Comment: Ha, that tells me - nothing. The problem I wanted to point to is: When you have shift-selection you can easily select many rows but won't have a way to deselect the easily.. - It is imperative to plan for the full set you want to implement!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bool variable on the KeyDown and KeyUp events (of the main form) to check if CTRL is pressed and then process the row indexes from the CellContentClick or any other of the events (which passes the Row and Column index, which can be used to set the Selected property). Just do an if clause, which checks if the CTRL pressed bool variable is set and then do your stuff.

Comment: +Gnqz I want the CTRL button to be pressed automatically without having anyone press it. So that it creates a multi-select effect. I don't get how your solution can achieve that.

Comment: What do you mean by "pressed automatically"?

Comment: I mean through the code. CTRL is always pressed as long as the form is open.

Comment: Then you could check the selected property of the cell in the CellContentClick event. Use gridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Selected to see if its selected and set it as you need. If I understand you correctly...

Comment: How exactly would that achieve multiple selections, unless I store each selected row in a list or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple workaround without having to modifying/inheriting DataGrid control by handling preview mouse down event as follows:

```
TheDataGrid.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(TheDataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);


void TheDataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // get the DataGridRow at the clicked point
    var o = TryFindFromPoint<DataGridRow>(TheDataGrid, e.GetPosition(TheDataGrid));
    // only handle this when Ctrl or Shift not pressed 
    ModifierKeys mods = Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.Modifiers;
    if (o != null && ((int)(mods & ModifierKeys.Control) == 0 && (int)(mods & ModifierKeys.Shift) == 0))
    {
        o.IsSelected = !o.IsSelected;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Method TryFindFromPoint is a borrowed function from this link http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent in order to get the DataGridRow instance from point you clicked

By checking ModifierKeys, you can still keep Ctrl and Shift as default behavior.

Only one draw back from this method is that you can't click and drag to perform range select like it can originally. But worth the try.

Comment: Sorry. I probably should have mentioned this is a WinForms project.

Comment: @Barry I would recommend you to go through msdn for this purpose as I have little knowledge on WinForms: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.multiselect(v=vs.110).aspx